# Run part 1 of php, after click (via jquery) run second part

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am making an online experiment where people need to click on a graph, press submit, click on a new graph, submit, and so on. the click value needs to be registered and saved on the server in a file.

My html file consists of different divs for the different charts. clicking submit with chart1 will hide that div and show the next div.

With my current html/jquery/php combo, I have the issue that **for div1, the code for saving the clicks from div2 also runs**. So my txt file looks like this after clicking chart1 (y=16), submit, and chart2 (y=52):

Coordinates according to chart location for plot1 : 9.088588588588589 - 16.032534246575345

Coordinates according to chart location for plot2 :  -

Coordinates according to chart location for plot1 :  -

Coordinates according to chart location for plot2 : 8.998498498498499 - 51.86815068493151

So php runs the 'log' action for both divs even when only the first div has been loaded and clicked. Can I make this more tidy? I could just remove the empty series manually, but the next version should have 15 charts and that would be a lot of work..

JS didn't display clearly if I posted it here, so I copy pasted it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ShariDB/kbe5fza2/

my php code:
'savetofile.php'

```
// get your data from the client
$xax = $_POST['xax'];
$yax = $_POST['yax'];

$out;

// validate $xax and $yax

// save your variables to a file
$result = file_put_contents("log.txt", PHP_EOL ."Coordinates according to chart location for plot1 : " . $xax . " - " . $yax, FILE_APPEND);

// tell the user what happened
if ($result !== FALSE) {
  $out = [ "message" => "success!", "status" => 200];
}
else {
  $out = [ "message" => "error saving file", "status" => 500];
}

// send stuff back to the client
echo json_encode($out);


// get your data from the client
$xax2 = $_POST['xax2'];
$yax2 = $_POST['yax2'];

$out;

// validate $xax and $yax

// save your variables to a file
$result = file_put_contents("log.txt", PHP_EOL ."Coordinates according to chart location for plot2 : " . $xax2 . " - " . $yax2, FILE_APPEND);

// tell the user what happened
if ($result !== FALSE) {
  $out = [ "message" => "success!", "status" => 200];
}
else {
  $out = [ "message" => "error saving file", "status" => 500];
}

// send stuff back to the client
echo json_encode($out);
exit();
```

On a final note: I was kind of hesitant to post this,  because I know my coding is messy. Everything I know is self-taught in the past five weeks and my knowledge of php is very limited. The code has also evolved from being designed for a locally hosted experiment to an online one. So please don't shoot me down :)

Comment: It looks like your code is working properly. There's nothing to stop the script after `plot1` so it goes on and processes `plot2`. If you want it to be AJAX, put it in a separate script and call that via your AJAX, or pass some query parameter and test for it first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I get what you're saying but I'm stuck on the practical solution. If I end the script after plot1, it won't re-run for the second graph (logical). Do I just use another php file? Then I would end up with 15 php files.. seems like they're should be a simpler solution, but I don't know how